# Insert data into MYSQL using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want a Registration form in which new users enter their details N he is registered /added in the database ,how do i add /Delete update information of Users in the Database MYSQL ?

**EDIT== NOTE->**

I M Following this tutorial line by line
SO the database part is from time 59:30 **LINK== https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAtVv1Q7ufM**

**User1Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using OnlineJobRecruitmentSystemMVC.Models;

 namespace OnlineJobRecruitmentSystemMVC.Controllers
{
 public class User1Controller : Controller
 {
    public PplContext db = new PplContext();
    //GET: User1
    public ActionResult User11()
    {
        var peoplefinal = db.people1.ToList();
         return View(peoplefinal);
     }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include =
 "1,'namai','passishere',1,1")] People personalDetail)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.people1.Add(personalDetail);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("User11");
        }

           return View(personalDetail);


    }
 }
}
```

**MODELS**

**1)People.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OnlineJobRecruitmentSystemMVC.Models
{
public class People
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String username { get; set; }
    public String password { get; set; }
    public int hasuploadedresume { get; set; }
    public int hasbeenselected { get; set; }
 }
}
```

**2)PplContext.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OnlineJobRecruitmentSystemMVC.Models
{
public class PplContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<People> people1 { get; set; }

}
}
```

**3)Ppldatabseinitializer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web;

namespace OnlineJobRecruitmentSystemMVC.Models
{
public class Ppldatabseinitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<PplContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(PplContext context)
    {
        var ppllist = new List<People>
        {
        new People { id = 1, username = "vaibhav123", password = "12345", hasuploadedresume = 0, hasbeenselected = 0 },
        new People { id = 2, username = "aman123", password = "12345", hasuploadedresume = 0, hasbeenselected = 0 }
         };
        foreach (var temp in ppllist)
        {
            context.people1.Add(temp);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

    }

}
}
```

**4)Web.config**
I added this line in web.config file only

```
<add name="PplContext" connectionString="Data Source=  (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdatabase.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-OnlineJobRecruitmentSystemMVC-20161105011202;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Is your database mysql? You are using MSSQL connection now. I think, You should learn some basic knowledge about  EF and configuration, Lots of resource available, google it first, May this article give you some ideas,  http://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-setup-mvc5-website-mysql-entity-framework-6-code-first-vs2013/

Comment: This might also be helpful https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: MAN I HAVE EDITED D QUESTION AS Per ur requirements n have written edit over there plz see edit